# Trying to match Color of button and its picture

Tags: c#

Basically, I need to match to match the Picture and the color, so that result will be that whenever I press the burger it becomes blue, and when I click something else it becomes green.

NOW it just randomly goes green or blue whenever I click the button with no reliance on the clicked picture.

Again, I need to match to match the picture and the color, so that result will be that whenever I press the burger it becomes blue, and when I click something else it becomes green.

I will now add screenshots of the form when it starts and what happens, and the entire code.

Thanks in advance.

Start : https://prnt.sc/jnad9j
When Clicked : https://prnt.sc/jnadie

CODE:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    cx = x;

    for (int j = 0; j<arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        value = rnd.Next(0, 2);
        t     = new Button();
        t.Tag = new Place(i, j);

        if (value == 0)
                rndmimg = rnd.Next(1, 2);
        else rndmimg = rnd.Next(2, 6);

        t.BackColor = Color.Red;
        t.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        t.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\Pictures\\"+rndmimg+".png");
        t.Bounds = new Rectangle(cx, y, w, h);
        t.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.qqq_Click);

        this.Controls.Add(t);
        arr [i, j] = t;
        cx += w;

    }

    y += h;
}

public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) => rnd = new Random();

private void qqq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int px;
    int py;

    Place pl = (Place)(((Button)sender).Tag);
    px = pl.GetR();
    py = pl.C;
    rndmcus = rnd.Next(0, 2);   // Rndmcus determines color when button is clicked

    if (rndmcus == 0)
    {
        mishvalue = 0;
        arr[px, py].BackColor = Color.Green;
        arr[px, py].Enabled = false;
    }

    if (rndmcus == 1)
    {
        mishvalue = 1;
        arr[px, py].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        arr[px, py].Enabled = false;
    }

    ((Button)sender).Text = " ";
    scanner();
}

public void scanner()
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(0); j++)
            if (arr[i, j].Text == " ")
                counter++;

    if (counter == boardsize * boardsize)
        this.Close();
}

class Place
{
    private int r;
    private int c;

    public Place(int r, int c)
    {
        this.r = r;
        this.c = c;
    }
    public int GetR()       => r;
    public int C            => c;
    public void SetR(int r) => this.r = r;
    public void SetC(int c) => this.c = c;
}
```

Comment: You should look into C# properties. Instead of using `GetC()` and `SetC(int c)` you can just do `C { get; private set; }` and the setter of C will be `private`.

Answer (score 1):

Assign all your button an id then access it in the event

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    value = rnd.Next(0, 2);
    t = new Button();
    t.ID = j.ToString();

Button button = (Button)sender;
string buttonId = button.ID;
```

Associate color with the id in like a Dictionary.